# How are multiple, alternative direct objects governed by multiple, alternative verbs?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

Title 18 USC Sec. 1519 begins:
Whoever knowingly alters, destroys, mutilates, conceals, covers up, falsifies, or makes a false entry in any record, document, or tangible object . . .

Question: Syntactically, must ALL the verbs be capable of applying to ALL the direct objects? (Or may the reader "mix & match"?)

Note the disjunctive OR used to relate both the verbs and the objects.

Comment: Simplify. Any person who eats or does crosswords in the boudoir or pigeon loft will be vapulated.

Comment: Thanks, but the situation is several alternative verbs, applying in turn to 3 alternative direct objects. Must EVERY verb work logically with EVERY direct object? Must "make a false entry in" work with "tangible object," even if the tangible object is a FISH? (Actual Supreme Court case)

Comment: 'The tooltips on the up- and down-vote arrows on questions explicitly mention research effort. ' [tchrist] I'm trying to point you towards a bit of research you could do and show here. Have you no problems with the simpler 2 transitive verbs (use 'grills or roasts lamb or chicken' if you think that fits better) and 2 DOs? Doesn't that suggest the general answer?

Comment: So, then, legally a person can (knowingly) destroy a true entry in a record, but not a false entry? (Next question: What if a person *unknowingly* destroys a false entry?)

Comment: @F.E. In that case the statute would not apply: it demands *mens rea*, "with the intent to impede, obstruct, or influence the investigation or proper administration of any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States".

Answer (score 1):

From the legal perspective is a fundamental **OR**

That is, if you perform any of the verbs on any of the objects, you are in violation and subject to dismemberment.

Answer (score 1):

The law embraces any of the verbs* governing any of the DOs; but of course in any specific instance only one of the verb governing only one DO will suffice to call the provision into operation.

---

* I personally cringe at that *makes a false entry in* acting alongside bare and phrasal verbs; but the Law is not so nice.

Comment: Thanks, but suppose the "tangible object" is a FISH (current Supreme Court case). Must "make a false entry in" apply to FISH?

Comment: @JRG2733 In this case, the defendant was accused of disposing of a fish.  He should have *eaten* the fish since this is not explicitly prohbited; but he can't carp about the verbiage.

Comment: @JRG2733 It is certainly possible under the intent of the act to make a false entry in **some** tangible objects: a tally stick, for instance. *Any tangible object* need not extend to *every tangible object*; but if a prosecutor demonstrates that some miscreant did in fact make a false entry in a fish with the intent to impede, obstruct, or influence the investigation or proper administration of any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States--by reprogramming a USFWS tracking chip, for instance?--the statutory penalties will apply.

Comment: Tx. FYI, fish were thrown overboard, I had not thought of falsifying a tracking chip.

Comment: @JRG2733 And of course the point at issue here is whether a fish is in fact a tangible object *within the meaning of the act*.

Comment: @StoneyB That is exactly the question, given that 1519 is an "anti shredding" provision of the Sarbanes Oxley Act. But I'm asking about the language (tracking chip notwithstanding). Tx.